# Gradient color interpolation for a list of values

Tags: r, colors, interpolation

I am sure versions of this question has been answered before but I am looking for a specific problem I am working on. 
I have a list of values for example:

```
[81,43,31,20,10,5,1,0]
```

I want to assign colors between white and black, higher the value the darker it gets fashion, to each one of these values.
So far in R I can use the `colorramppalette` function and the image function assigns these colors to the values in my `heatmap` automatically.
I want to learn how to assign these colors manually to get more control over the coloring aspect of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vec = c(81,43,31,20,10,5,1,0)
myColors = c("red", "blue")
myRangeFunction = colorRampPalette(myColors)
myColorRange = myRangeFunction(max(vec))
myColors = myColorRange[vec]
plot(x = seq_along(vec),
     y = vec,
     cex = 2,
     pch = 19,
     col = myColors)
```